# Is there a github actions 'playground' or sandbox for trying out github actions syntax?

Tags: github, yaml, action

I'm looking for a way to quickly validate github actions yaml that I write. Is there an interactive web page for doing this? Or is github just using some standard language that I can run locally on my mac?

Comment: There is a tool called act (https://github.com/nektos/act) that can run actions locally using docker.